Alternar el color de placeholder de un input
Hola busco crear como una especie de intervalo para el color del texto del placeholder de un input
puedo hacerlo únicamente con css?
o es necesario js

Lee [ask] y el [tour].

Hola, fácilmente lo puedes hacer sin ayuda de JS.

Primero: Puedes darle estilo a un placeholder usando el seudoselector ::placeholder. El siguiente ejemplo aparece en MDN


input {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: red;
}
<label for="first-name">Your phone number:</label><br />

<input id="first-name" type="tel" name="phone" minlength="9" maxlength="9" placeholder="It must be 9 digits" />



Segundo, puedes colorear un texto con gradientes usando
background: <gradiente>;
color: transparent;
background-clip: text;

El siguiente ejemplo es una modificación de CSSGradient.io


h1 {
  background: linear-gradient(#a00, #00c);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
<h1>Ejemplo</h1>



Tercero: combinando las dos anteriores, puedes hacer un placeholder con gradiente.


input {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

input::placeholder {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(237, 0, 25, 1) 0%, rgba(53, 168, 187, 1) 60%);
  color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
}
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder del input">



